# If I have $\lfloor\frac{E}{K}\rfloor =\lfloor \frac{E}{K + m}\rfloor$, what is the upper limit of 'm' in terms of 'E' and 'k'

Tags: inequality, fractions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given that `E, K, m > 0`, then is there a way to find out value of `m` in terms of `E` and `K` for

$$\left\lfloor\frac{E}{K} \right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{E}{K + m} \right\rfloor$$

All I have gotten so far is this:

$$ \frac{E}{K}-1 \lt \left\lfloor\frac{E}{K}\right\rfloor \le \frac{E}{K} $$

and,

$$ \frac{E}{K+m}-1 \lt \left\lfloor\frac{E}{K+m}\right\rfloor \le \frac{E}{K+m} $$

and since $\left\lfloor\frac{E}{K} \right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{E}{K + m} \right\rfloor$,

$$ \implies \frac{E}{K}-1 <  \frac{E}{K + m} $$

leading to,

$$ m < \frac{K^2}{E - K} $$

but I am looking for a tighter bound, preferably in terms of equality. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to add that $ E \gt K $

Comment: What about $m\leq \frac{E}{\lfloor E/K\rfloor} -K$? ;-)

Comment: I cannot follow your calculation and think there is a mistake. Anyway, let's assume $E > K$, otherwise the question is rather uninteresting. We get
$$ \frac{E}{K + m} > \frac{E}{K}-1 = \frac{E-K}{K} $$
$$ K + m <  \frac{EK}{E-K}$$
$$ m <  \frac{EK}{E-K}-K = \frac{EK-K(E-K)}{E-K} = \frac{EK-KE+ K^2}{E-K} = \frac{K^2}{E-K}.$$

And this is a much better estimate than yours, e.g for $E=5, K=2$ we get $m < 4/3$ (your estimate is 25/3).

Comment: I am sorry, I posted it wrong, I got exactly what you got and I was hoping to get tighter bounds.